# Totally geodesic subgroups in Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, geodesics

Let $G$ be a Lie group with a **left** invariant metric $g$.

Let $H$ be a (closed) Lie subgroup of $G$, and assume $g$ is **right**-$H$-invariant. (That is $d(R_h)_e:T_eG \to T_hG$ is an isometry for every $h \in H$). Note that this is equivalent to the statement, that for every $h \in H$ the map of right multiplication by $h$, viewed as a map $G \mapsto G$ is an isometry.

(This appears to be stronger thant requiring it will be an isometry as a map $H \mapsto H$).

Is it true that $H$ must be totally geodesic in $G$?

Since $g$ is bi-$H$-invariant, the geodesics of $H$ are the one-parameter subgroups of $H$. Hence, the question amounts to:

Are the one-parameter subgroups of $H$ geodesics in $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit.** I totally misunderstood the question, maybe now its better.
Assume that $g$ is left-$G$ and right-$H$-invariant. Then one can construct a Riemannian submersion $p\colon G\to G/H$. This is now a family of Riemannian manifolds with fibre $H$ and compact structure group $H$, because you could also write it as a Borel construction $G=G\times_HH\to G/H$. Here, you regard $G$ as a principal bundle over $G/H$ with fibre $H$. $G/H$ is equipped with the induced Riemannian metric, and $T^HG\subset TG$ is defined as $\ker(dp)^\perp$. Together with the induced metric on $H$, the Borel construction gives back the original metric $g$. But then its fibres are automatically totally geodesic, so now the answer is "yes".

**Old answer to a different question :-)**
Consider Berger metrics on $SU(2)\cong S^3\subset\mathbb C^2$.
Here the round metric is stretched or shrunk along the fibres of the Hopf
fibration $S^3\to S^2$. These metrics are still left invariant, but
not biinvariant. For $H$, take a one parameter subgroup, so $H\cong S^1$.
The induced metric on $H$ is still left invariant, hence biinvariant, because $H$ is abelian.

If all one parameter subgroups were geodesics, then their left translates by elements of $SU(2)$ would be geodesics, too. So the Berger metrics would have the same geodesics as the round metric, but that is not the case. Hence, the answer in general is no.

Comment: is a Berger metric right $H$-invariant as in the OP question?.  It is clear that the induced metric on $H$ is indeed bi-invariant. But it seems clear that the OP is assuming that the metric $g$ is right $H$-invariant over all the group $G$ and not just on itself. But perhaps I am misunderstanding the OP question.

Comment: Indeed, I am assuming $g$ is right $H$-invariant over all $G$. That is, I meant for $d(R_h)_e:T_eG \to T_hG $ to be an isometry $\, \, \forall  h \in H$.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette: in the OP question the group $H$ is not assumed to be compact as you wrote. But perhaps this is not important for the Borel construction you have in mind, isn't it?

Comment: @Holonomia You are right. It suffices that $H$ acts isometrically on the typical fibre, which it does here. If I find some time, I will look up a reference for this construction (maybe Berline-Getzler-Vergne).

Comment: @Sebastian Goette: is the 'Borel construction' in your answer the 'fundamental construction' at page 12 of Donaldson's notes http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~skdona/LIEGROUPSCONSOL.PDF  ?  Unfortunately, in Donaldson's fundamental construction there are no involved Riemannian metrics nor totally geodesic submanifolds. So would be nice if you provide a reference where all calculations can we followed.